# How can I fix Missing WebSocket ServerContainer enabling WebSockets with CometD, Jetty and Spring?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, cometd

I'm experiencing a problem trying to enable WebSockets on CometD. My configuration is the following:

- CometD 3.0.5

- Jetty 9.0.6, 

- SpringMVC 3.2.4


web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometDServlet</servlet-class>
            <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </servlet>
    </web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
  <bean id="bayeuxServer" class="org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="options">
            <map>
                <entry key="javax.servlet.ServletContext" value-ref="servletContext" />
                <entry key="ws.cometdURLMapping" value="/cometd/*" />
                <entry key="logLevel" value="0" />
                <entry key="timeout" value="15000" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="transports">
            <list>
                <bean id="websocketTransport" class="org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport">
                    <constructor-arg ref="bayeuxServer" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The exception that I'm getting is the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing WebSocket ServerContainer
    at org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport.init(WebSocketTransport.java:81)
    at org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl.initializeServerTransports(BayeuxServerImpl.java:260)
    at org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl.doStart(BayeuxServerImpl.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1608)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at com.app.gui.web.appContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(appContextLoaderListener.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at com.app.jetty.AppJettyServer.main(appJettyServer.java:189)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a serious mismatch in the versions of the libraries you are using.
Stick with CometD 3.0.6, Jetty 9.2.13 and Spring 4.2.2.

The recommended way to setup a skeleton CometD web application is to follow the [primer instructions](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_primer).
If you use Maven, this boils down to a single line to create a skeleton CometD web application that works out of the box using the Jetty Maven Plugin:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://cometd.org
```

Otherwise you can take the generated `war` file and deploy it to Jetty following [these instructions](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_deploying_your_cometd_application).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upgrade Jetty and I can't upgrade Spring. Which version of CometD will be suitable for Jetty 9.0.6 and SpringMVC 3.2.4?

Comment: Anyway I did make a copy of the entire project and tried with your configuration, still no luck...

Comment: Like Joakim said, Jetty 9.0.x does not have a WebSocket implementation that is compatible with CometD 3. The earliest version for CometD 3 is Jetty 9.2.1.

Comment: I did used the libraries that you pointed out. It worked smooth. It would be useful to have some kind of table of version compatibility. Where can I find it?

Comment: http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_requirements_and_dependencies. For a more precise list of dependencies, the CometD root POM file is the main reference: https://github.com/cometd/cometd/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your version of Jetty to 9.2.x series.

9.0.x does not have the JSR356 support your configuration is attempting to enable.

As of Oct 2015, the latest stable Jetty 9.2.x series release is `9.2.13.v20150730`

Comment: Don't use the `jetty-all` artifact for your build ([that's not what the artifact exists for](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html))

Comment: do a `$ mvn dependency:tree` and edit your question to include the output.